# In Laravel db migration commands; it is not possible to create a column which is BOTH unique and greater than 191 in size. How to solve?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

**First**; according to [this](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error)

I edited: `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
   Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

**Second**; I issued `php artisan make:migration create_users`

**Third**; I implemented the generated class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
           Schema::create('users2',function($users){
           $users->increments('id');
           $users->string('email',320)->unique(); // this causes errors
           $users->string('username',100)->unique();
           $users->string('password',50);
           $users->rememberToken();
           $users->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users2');
    }
}
```

**Fourth**; after issuing `php artisan migrate`

I get this result:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length
>   is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users2` add unique
>   `users2_email_unique`(`email`))
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

The problem is in this line:
`$users->string('email',320)->unique();`

When I checked the database; I found the `email` column created with the specified length 320 but NOT unique `UNI`

If length is set to 191 or less, then the `email` column is created properly with the specified length and uniqueness.

So how to allow the creation of columns which are both unique and not limited to the 191 ceiling?!

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations; it explains what's going on with that under the heading **Index Lengths & MySQL / MariaDB**. Some versions of MySQL don't handle the `utf8mb4` encoding, but overrding this is `config/database` to something like `utf8/utf8_general_ci` fixed it for my most recent use case.

Comment: Instead of making the `email` a `unique` key, add a column `email_hash`, hash the actual email and make that column unique. If you store raw binary representation of `sha1` email digest as `binary(20)` (mysql type), you will always use 20 bytes for the index instead of variable length, as you never know how long the actual email may be. Naturally, you can completely ignore my suggestion and try to hack your way through MySQL's key length limits and UTF8.